# Regex matching non space character

Tags: javascript, regex, cookies

I am trying to extract cookies from a netscape format cookie file using JavaScript and regex. The regex used works in php and python but for some reason it doesnt work on JavaScript. It returns no matches. When instead of [\S] i use [^\s] it gives matches but it cuts out the character 's', which is not optimal...
Anyway this is the code and the test string, let me know if its something obvious.

```
function readCookies(){
    fs.readFile(myArgs[0], 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(data);
        var rx = new RegExp("(\S*?)\t(\S*?)\t(\S*?)\t(\S*?)\t(\S*?)\t(\S*?)\t(\S+)", "g");
        var matches = new Array();
        var name = true;
        while((match = rx.exec(data)) !== null){
            console.log(String(match[1]).trim())
        }
    });
    }
```

Test String:

```
 # Netscape HTTP Cookie File
    # http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
    # This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

    sffd.com    FALSE   /   FALSE   1418953710  proimg  709c76
    sffd.com    FALSE   /   FALSE   1418953710  proimg1 709c76
    .sffd.com   FALSE   /   FALSE   1418953710  proimg2 709c76
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not escaping your backslashes in your RegExp string. The alternative is to use the RegExp literal syntax:

```
var rx = /(\S*?)\t(\S*?)\t(\S*?)\t(\S*?)\t(\S*?)\t(\S*?)\t(\S+)/g;
```

Also on an unrelated note, you're introducing `match` as a global as far as I can tell. So you might want to add `var match;` before the while loop.